# Dots on UIBarButtonItem

Tags: ios, ipad, uisplitviewcontroller, uibarbuttonitem, ellipsis

I am seeing some dots trailing one of my UIBarButtonItems (see image). They don't always show up; it is somewhat random. Though I have noticed that opening a modal or rotating the device tends to make them appear or disappear. That specific button is the only one that does it. That button opens a split view controllers master view.

[image]

I thought the icon size was too big, so I changed the icon and the icon size, but that did not fix it. I am not setting the title, just the icon. I am following the [iOS HIG](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UserExperience/Conceptual/MobileHIG/IconMatrix.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40006556-CH27-SW1) that specifies icons on the navigation bar to be 22x22, 44x44 and 66x66.

Has anyone seen this? What did you do to get around it?

Answer (score 0):

Did you expand the button itself. Sometimes the text/icon is too big and the button is too small.

Comment: did that work if not I don't really know what else to do.

Comment: that did not work. I posted an answer that worked. It's a hack. This is most likely a bug on Apples side.

Answer (score 0):

I was able to solve it by setting the `title`:

```
barButtonItem.title = @" ";
```

It is definitely a hack and definitely a bug on Apples side. If anyone else has a better solution, please let me know.